# In Google Drive SDK how do you copy a folder?

Tags: google-drive-api

Very simple question. How can I copy a folder with the Google Drive API?

It looks like the file/copy API endpoint doesn't work with folders (though this limitation is not clearly indicated in the documentation).

Of course I could add a second parent to the file, but obviously that's not a solution as most of the time a folder copy is done to do something with it without modifying the original.

So how can I do that? Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

'copy' wouldn't make much sense on a folder. The purpose of copy is to create a second file with the same media content as the first. Since a folder has no media content, 'copy' doesn't really apply.

To answer the question, we need to understand your use case a little. Take a *nix paradigm, "cp -R folder1 folder2" is recursively duplicating all of the files. If that is your use case, you'll need to manually recurse down the tree. If you want the same files to appear in two places, (ie. "ln -s folder1 folder2") then that is done by adding a second parent.

Comment: Make sense. My use case is indeed the unix "cp" command. Recursively duplicate seems a decent way to deal with this operation that may be expensive on the server side. Thank you for your answer pinoyyid!

Comment: @pinoyyid Is this still the case, 2 years later?

Comment: @JagWire I think it still is after 4 years :D

Comment: I don't see this ever changing. The Drive API provides low level primitives which allow you to do everything that can be done. Higher level functions, such as a recursive copy, will always be something you need to do yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I've published a pypi package to copy a google drive folder. It basically implements the recursive behaviour described in the first answer

https://pypi.org/project/googledrive-cloner/