# Google drive API - Copy Folder

Tags: rest, api, google-drive-api

I'm unable to copy whole folder (files, subfolders) recursively using google drive api

Searched all over the API documentation and the web for such API but couldn't find any.
I also considered implementing it by my self (recursive copy) but this option is too risky because the number of the files vary.
(I even talked with google support!)

**UPDATE:**
I managed to reach one of the Google Drive API developers.
"There is no API method to copy an entire folder, you have to do it file-by-file, subfolder-by-subfolder."

Comment: See [Make a Copy of Folders in Google Drive with Google Scripts](https://ctrlq.org/code/19979-copy-folders-drive) and [In Google Drive SDK how do you copy a folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605318/in-google-drive-sdk-how-do-you-copy-a-folder)

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. Where do you want to copy the files from Google Drive to? 2. What language do you want to use?

Comment: **Eliahu**, both of the solutions suggest to copy the folders recursively which for me its not an option. I also work with Dropbox and their API do it for you so you.
**Tankaie**, I just want to clone the folder in the same root, I'm using JAVA but i'm looking for a REST solution (not sdk)